# SUGBR December 11th meetup

Tags: discussion, status-completed

AGENDA:

18:30 - 19:00 (21:30 - 22:00 UTC) - Networking and snacks (local only - sorry :P)

19:00 - 19:45 (22:00 - 22:45 UTC) - "Sitecore Experience Forms" with Sitecore MVPs Kamruz Jaman and Mike Reynolds (SESSION IN ENGLISH)

19:45 - 20:00 (22:45 - 23:00 UTC) - Q&A

20:10 - 20:55 (23:10 - 23:55 UTC) - "Integration Tests and Sitecore: Our experience using Nightwatch" with Hugo Santos (SESSION IN PORTUGUESE)

20:55 - 21:10 (23:55 - 00:10 UTC) - Q&A